# Cancelling / Stopping ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE

Tags: sql-server, index, fragmentation

```
ALTER INDEX [myIndex] ON [dbo].[myTable] REORGANIZE WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION = ON )
```

I have the above query running for 16 days (still running), the table is a dummy table used for benchmark tests, it has over 10 Billion rows. (About 1 TB of data including `myIndex` (non-clustered)).

I know there is progress as when I query for fragmentation, I see the number decrease.

If I cancel / stop the execution of the `ALTER INDEX`, can I resume it later safely, or will it cause to a rollback?

**Will it rollback roll just the last page swapped or the whole operation ?**

Comment: You can also see the progress in sys.dm_exec_requests.percent_complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can stop a reorganize and it won't cause a big rollback like you are talking about.  You will be left with where the operation left off (that's a good thing).  It's a rebuild that would have the rollback behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I couldn't find this information in an official source, can you link to one?

Comment: Here's the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#reorganize-an-index